# Get the id of a saved object using Sails

Tags: node.js, sails.js

If I save an object like that:

```
Pet.create({name:'Pinkie Pie',color:'pink'}).exec();
```

How can I retrieve the id of the saved object without perform another query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it passing an anonymous function as a callback:

```
Pet.create({name:'Pinkie Pie',color:'pink'}).exec(function createCB(err,pet) {
    console.log(pet.id);
}
```